# How to signal when AJAX completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, signals

I have two ajax `$.get()` requests that I need to synchronize.

Essentially

```
var signal1 = false;
var signal2 = false;

    $.get(url,
                {},
                function (data) { 
                    signal1 = true;//callback complete.
                },'json');

    $.get(url2,
                {},
                function (data) { 
                    signal2 = true;//callback complete.
                },'json');

    when(signal1 && signal2 == true)
       $.get(url3...
```

How can I, should I accomplish this type of task?  (Bonus, what's the AJAX signature for failure callback?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
$.when(
    $.get(url, {}, function(data) { 
        // signal 1 complete
    }, 'json'),
    $.get(url2, {}, function(data) { 
        // signal 2 complete
    }, 'json')
).then(function() {
    // success after both methods finish
}, function() {
    // failure method
});
```

See `jQuery.when`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Both answers are great.  You get answer credit because you also knocked out the bonus question.

Comment: Note that an alternative to `.then(success_func).fail(failure_func)` is just `.then(sucess_func, failure_func)`. They both work. I prefer to explicitly spell it out with the `fail` method though.

Comment: Something is not working.  I noticed the callback here is defined in the `$.get()`.  This is actually ok, better I think...but legal?  The code I find online defines the callbacks inside of `then()`.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, I updated it to use the second form I mentioned in my comment, `.then(success_func, failture_func)`

Comment: And using `$.get` is fine. Internally, it just shorthand for a specific `$.ajax` call.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the jquery deferred/promise methods, they are for exactly what you are trying to do.

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).done(function(a1,  a2){
   // a1 and a2 are the results of your two calls.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Comment: How do you define the return type with this syntax?  (html/json)

Comment: You could either use the specific methods ($.get/$.getJSON) or expand the call to $.ajax to specify. Is that what you mean?